# LINQ find MAX value of set of values within a larger set

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table named "PostFiv with the following columns:

ID
ForeignKey
Digit
RemarkText

What I am trying to do is find the max value of the 'Digit' within the table, where the ForeignKey is the same, and into a string. If we assume the following data:

```
Id    |ForeignKey    |Digit    |RemarkText
1     |ABB           |1        |ipsum lorem
2     |ABB           |2        |ipsum lorem
3     |ACC           |1        |ipsum lorem
4     |AFF           |1        |ipsum lorem
5     |ABB           |3        |ipsum lorem
```

So I want to query the DB with linq, and ask for the max value of the Digit where the ForeignKey=ABB, and add 1. I expect the answer to be 4, in a string.

I was playing around with this:

```
postFiv.Digit = _context.PostFiv.Range(m => m.ForeignKey == postFiv.ForeignKey).Max(postFiv.Digit).ToString();
```

But it's definitely not right. Thanks!

EDIT 201008
I changed the "Digit" from string to int, which works better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var elements = _context.PostFiv
        .Where(m => m.ForeignKey == postFiv.ForeignKey)
        .ToArray();

if(!elements.Any())
    postFiv.Digit = 1;
else
    postFiv.Digit = elements.Max(x => x.Digit) + 1;
```

`Where` will filter set by criteria `m.ForeignKey == postFiv.ForeignKey` and return collection of items (can be empty). Then check that you have some records and handle if there are no elements with given key. Then call `Max(x => x.Digit)` to find max `Digit` and add one to it.

Comment: Hey, the answer came back as "11", instead of "2". Any thoughts? The "Digit" is a string... my fault...

Comment: @NickFleetwood Did you call add one before call `ToString()` on max `Digit`?

Comment: Apparently `x.Digit` is `String` so for `Max` to work properly, and addition, you need to parse...

Comment: Update to string `x.Digit`

Comment: That seems like it should work. But I got this error: KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'EmptyProjectionMember' was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: @NickFleetwood Try to add ".DefaultIfEmpty(0)" before your Max().

Comment: @Yinqiu nope. I get "InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<PostThr> .Where(m => m.ThrZero == __postThr_ThrZero_0) .Select(x => int.Parse(x.ThrDigit)) .DefaultIfEmpty(__p_1)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed."

Comment: @SergeyNazarov Ok, I changed to int. I thought about it, and it's not a big deal for me whether it is int or string, and it's probably better as int. After that, it works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry. This only works as long as there are other records with the same FK. If there are no other elements, returns :Sequence contains no elements. Please advise, and I can mark you up

Comment: @NickFleetwood So, what behaviour you are awaiting, if there are no elements with given FK?

Comment: @NickFleetwood I don't know logic of your app. So, you should handle empty elements with required behaviour. I updated post: at if statement you can handle it.

Comment: @SergeyNazarov i feel like it should be something like "If count of FK = 0 THEN 1, ELSE _context.PostThrs.Where(m => m.ThrZero == postThr.ThrZero).Max(x => x.ThrDigit) + 1;"

Comment: @NickFleetwood Please, check it up.

Answer (score 1):

So for all PostFivs with ForeignKey ABB you want the largest Digit, for all PostFivs that have ForeignKey ACC you want the largest Digit etc.

Whenever you have a sequence, and you want to make items based on something that items from this sequence have in common, consider to use one of the [overloads of Queryable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby)

In your case: you want to extract the largest Digit for all PostFivs that have the same value for ForeignKey.

The idea is that you make Groups of items where every item has the same value of something, in your case: the same value of ForeignKey. Use parameter resultSelector to created one item per Group.

```
var result = dbContext.PostFivs.GroupBy(

    // parameter keySelector: make groups of PostFivs that have same ForeignKey
    postFiv => postFiv.ForeignKey,

    // parameter resultSelector: take each common item (= ForeignKey),
    // and all PostFives that have this value for ForeignKey, to make one new
    (foreignKey, postFivsWithThisForeignKey) => ...);
```

In the resultSelector, in the (..., ...) part, the first parameter is the common item, the second parameter is the sequence of all postFivs that have this common item. Note: the second parameter is an enumerable sequence, so you can use LINQ on this second parameter.

In your case, from all postFivs with this foreign key, you only want the largest Digit as a string. Luckily, you can be certain that there is at least one element in the group, so you can use Max:

```
(foreignKey, postFivsWithThisForeignKey) => postFivsWithThisForeignKey
    .Select(postFiv => postFiv.Digit)
    .Max()
    .ToString()
```

If you wanted something else, for instance the foreignKey and several other properties of the postFivs that have this foreign key, you can just create a new object:

```
(foreignKey, postFivsWithThisForeignKey) => new
{
    ForeignKey = foreignKey

    NonNullRemarkTexts = postFivsWithThisForeignKey
        .Where(postFive => postFiv.RemarkText != null)
        .Select(postFiv => new
        {
            Id = postFiv.Id,
            RemarkText = postFiv.RemarkText,
        })
        .ToList(),
});
```